# named query not accepting % operator as sql

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, named-query

I am trying to run a named query in my spring/hibernate code  but it is returning error in my named query.
The query is

```
select count(*) from
(select distinct td.ticketId,td.taskName as names 
from TaskWorklog td 
where td.taskName LIKE CONCAT ('%' , ^SubTask, '%')
and (td.taskName not in (
select td.taskName from TaskWorklog td 
where td.taskName LIKE CONCAT ('%' , ^SubTask, '%') and td.operationType in (3,5,6,9,11,13,15,17,24)))) as twd1 where twd1.ticketId=etm.ticketId
group by twd1.ticketId) as open_subtask
```

Could you please tell an alternative or the error in the same, as I am no able to understand the error.

Caused by:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries:
>   fetchPendingForMyActionDetails at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:532)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1797)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1868)
>   at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)

Comment: What does the error look like?

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: fetchPendingForMyActionDetails
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:532)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1797)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1868)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)

Comment: Its a general error not any specific kind of thing. P.S. "fetchPendingForMyActionDetails" is the name of the query